# Trouble converting file types by calling a program from the terminal

Tags: python-3.x, input

I'm trying to automate a process of taking in a 'pdb' file from user input and then using that input file in a program called from the Terminal called 'Antechamber' that outputs a 'mol2'file.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

inFile = sys.argv[tetrafluoroborate.pdb]

outFile = sys.argv[tetrafluoroborate.mol2]

p = 'antechamber' + ' -i ' + inFile + ' fi pdb o- ' +  outFile  + ' -fo mol2'

subprocess.call(p)
```

The Antechamber program takes four commands: '-i' is the input file, '-fi' is the output file type, '-o' is the output file, and '-fo' is the output file format.

When I run the script, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    inFile = sys.argv[tetrafluoroborate.pdb]
NameError: name 'tetrafluoroborate' is not defined
```

I'm new to coding, and I appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. You're right, ideally I would be able to use different inputs and outputs. I'm trying different variations of what you suggested, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Here's one of my attempts:          import subprocess
import sys


inFile = sys.argv[tetrafluoroborate.pdb]

outFile = sys.argv[tetrafluoroborate.mol2]

lst = sys.argv[inFile, outFile]

p = 'antechamber' + ' -i ' + lst[0] + ' fi pdb o- ' +  lst[1]  + ' -fo mol2'

subprocess.call(p)

And I was still getting the same error. Could you help clarify to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the antechamber script from python and the input and output names will have the same prefix, I would suggest a python script like this:

```
import sys

prefix = sys.argv[1]

inFile = prefix + '.pdb'
outFile = prefix + '.mol2'

pcommand = 'antechamber' + ' -i ' + inFile + ' -fi pdb -o ' +  outFile  + ' -fo mol2'
subprocess.call(pcommand)
```

Then you can call from the command line by:

```
python test.py tetrafluoroborate
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it looks like a nice, succinct way of doing what I want to do. I ran it and got some errors, and I don't have the characters to do it in this post, so I'll do two.                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.call(pcommand)
  File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

Comment: File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'antechamber -i tetrafluoroboarate.pdb -fi pdb -o tetrafluoroboarate.mol2 -fo mol2': 'antechamber -i tetrafluoroboarate.pdb -fi pdb -o tetrafluoroboarate.mol2 -fo mol2'

Comment: It's not finding one of the files. There is a misspelling in "tetrafluoroboarate" there that may be the cause.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, there was that spelling error. When I type the name in correctly I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 12, in <module>
    subprocess.call(pcommand)
  File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child

Comment: File "/home/software/anaconda/3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'antechamber -i tetrafluoroborate.pdb -fi pdb -o tetrafluoroborate.mol2 -fo mol2': 'antechamber -i tetrafluoroborate.pdb -fi pdb -o tetrafluoroborate.mol2 -fo mol2'

Comment: Looks like it's not finding one of the files. Maybe if you specify the entire path to antechamber and the input pdb file?

Comment: I did what you said, and I added args = vars(parser.parse_args()) and subprocess.call(pcommand, shell=True) to the script, and now it's up and running! Thanks for all of your help.